# How can I set the default alert settings for calendar events added from Mail

Tags: mail.app, calendar

By hovering over a date or time in Mail, you can add a calendar event. However, by default, all of the events I add in this way do not give me any kind of notification before they occur. The only way I have found to change this setting is to click details, and then manually add an alert. Is there any way to add an alert by default, to all events created in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to Calendar settings where you can choose defaults:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried this? My Calendar settings are identical to yours, but defaults in Mail are unaffected.

Comment: You're right, alerts added through Mail.app don't get default alerts. I just added a couple things and was not notified.